# Index in pandas.to_sql, ValueError: duplicate name in index/columns: cannot insert id, already exists

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, indexing

I am reading and writing MySQL table with pandas and I am pretty sure that the value I am trying to set as index during writing is unique.
I checked the table without an index and `count(distinct(id))` gives the same amount of rows as `count(id)`.
However, I still get an error

```
'ValueError: duplicate name in index/columns: cannot insert product_id, already exists'
```

if i set 
`index=True, index_label="id"`

I have tried `reset_index`, but it did not help.

`df.to_sql(name=config.DB_TABLE, con=connection, schema=config.DB_SCHEMA, if_exists='fail', index=True, index_label="id")`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you writing the table, "replace" or "append"? If it's "append", it might duplicate with existing values in that column. Can you show us the database table schema and your code for `to_sql`?

Comment: @YilunZhang I delete the table before writing to it, so it does not even exist before to_sql execution

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by setting the index of the DataFrame before calling the `to_sql()` method:

```
df = df.set_index('your_index')
```

I believe the method wouldn't accept the index I specified as it was already trying to use the default pandas index (i.e. `0, 1, 2...`). Setting the DataFrame's index to the one you want in your database will avoid this conflict

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was wondering. The problem was, that in the mean time while programming I had added a column into my DataFrame. Consequently, the columns did not match with the SQL Columns anymore. You should check the matching of your columns.